# pdftotext all files in subdirectories if it doesn't already exist

Tags: bash, pdf, while-loop, find, pdftotext

I need to pdftotext all files in a subdirectory if the text file doesn't already exist.  I've tried:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | while read file; if [ ! -e $file.txt ] do pdftotext $file; done;
```

but receive: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | while IFS= read -r file; do if [ ! -e "$file.txt" ]; then pdftotext "$file"; fi; done
```

---

See: `help while` and `help if`

Answer (score 0):

Don't pipe the data to a shell; execute a shell loop from *within* `find`.

```
script='
  for f in "$@"; do
    if ! [ -e "$f" ]; then
      pdftotext "$f"
    fi
  done
'
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c "$script" _ {} +
```

This will work for *any* valid file name, even one containing a newline. `find` will pass as many files as possible to the script each time it is invoked, and invoke the script as many times as necessary to process all the files.